# Aforge.Genetic, Fitness function

Tags: aforge, fitness

Please, help me with creation a fitness function for chromosome with type "DoubleArrayChromosome". My chromosome contains coefficients of polynomial.

Would you give me some examples or advices how to write correct code for this type population.

Now I have only this:

```
AForge.Math.Random.IRandomNumberGenerator chGenerator = 
     new AForge.Math.Random.ExponentialGenerator(0.01f);
DoubleArrayChromosome ch = 
     new DoubleArrayChromosome(chGenerator, chGenerator, chGenerator, 10);
```

P.S. Sorry for my English...

Comment: This is not a forum. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Come back when you have a specific issue. Your english is fine, don't worry about it :)